# Change name of custom post type after using it

Tags: wordpress, rename, custom-post-type, slug

I want to change the name of a custom post type after I'm using it for a long time.

The current name is registered like this:

`register_post_type( 'toremove-name' , $args );`

And I want it this way:

`register_post_type( 'name' , $args );`

If I change it, I think it will make problems in the DB. 
Is there a way or a plugin to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there is a plugin, but if you have MySQL access, you can also just rename the CPT the way you have indicated and perform am SQL query to update:

UPDATE  `wp_posts` SET  `post_type` =  `New CPT Name` WHERE  `post_type` = `Old CPT Name`;

Also, don't forget your taxonomies if you have any registered to the CPT. You might have to flush your permalinks after you performed this action